# Local variable to property of class

Tags: linq, class, properties, var

I have created an a list using linq. Unfortunately i want to have it as a property of a class. How can i convert it to a accessable property of a class?

```
public class Component {

    // Property of class Component
    public string Komponentenart { get; set;}
    public int KomponentenID { get; set;}
    public string KomponentenArtikelnummer { get; set;}
    public var Variablen { get; set; }
}

public Component(string _filename)
{
    string componentFile = _filename;
try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(componentFile, Encoding.UTF8);
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);


            var variablen = (from element in xmlDoc.Descendants("variable")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Variable = (string)element.Attribute("ID"),
                                 Index = (string)element.Attribute("index"),
                                 Name = (string)element.Attribute("name"),
                                 Path = (string)element.Attribute("path"),
                                 Interval = (string)element.Attribute("interval"),
                                 ConnectorId = (string)element.Attribute("connectorId"),
                                 Type = (string)element.Attribute("type"),
                                 Factor = (string)element.Attribute("factor"),
                                 MaxValue = (string)element.Attribute("maxvalue")
                             }
                ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return instances of anonymous types as return value of functions or properties (From my latest information. A quick google search yielded no indication that that's changed so far). Which means you can't make a list of an anonymous type like you are creating with `new {VariableName1 = "123", VarName2 = "456"}`.
You could define a class or struct which has the members you need, such as Variable, Index, Name, Path. Then when you build your list, instead of creating an oject with `new {...}`, you create one of a named type, i.e.:

Define this somewhere:

```
class MyBunchOfVariables
{
public string Variable  ;
public string Index         ;
public string Name      ;
public string Path      ;
public string Interval  ;
public string ConnectorId ;
public string Type      ;
public string Factor        ;
public string MaxValue  ;
}
```

Modify the property type accordingly:

```
public class Component
{
// Property of class Component
public string Komponentenart { get; set;}
public int KomponentenID { get; set;}
public string KomponentenArtikelnummer { get; set;}
public MyBunchOfVariables Variablen { get; set}; // ### CHANGED TYPE ###
}
```

And then:

```
var variablen = (from element in xmlDoc.Descendants("variable")
             select
            new MyBunchOfVariables
                {
                 Variable       = (string)element.Attribute("ID"),
                 Index      = (string)element.Attribute("index"),
                 Name       = (string)element.Attribute("name"),
                 Path       = (string)element.Attribute("path"),
                 Interval       = (string)element.Attribute("interval"),
                 ConnectorId        = (string)element.Attribute("connectorId"),
                 Type       = (string)element.Attribute("type"),
                 Factor         = (string)element.Attribute("factor"),
                 MaxValue       = (string)element.Attribute("maxvalue")
                }
                ).ToList();
```

Comment: Prisoned in mental frustration about this topic i found this solution myself. I was still in programming when your information arrived. The solution works exactly as desired. It seems so easy if you know how to do it. Thank you for your help!